# How to escape two forward slashes in Ruby Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to make a regex which finds the domain name using Ruby, so I tried this:

```
(?<=.*/).(?=.*/)
```

On Rubular I always see this error message: `Forward slashes must be escaped.`

How do I solve this?

Comment: The title mentions backslashes, whereas the question mentions forward slashes. Which?

Comment: In case you are unfamiliar with the nomenclature, to "escape" a character means to inserts a backslash before it, so `/` becomes `\/`.  This is so that won't get confused when the original character has a special meaning when it is not escaped.  Also, Ruby (and other languages) escape some characters to make them have special meaning.  In a regex, for example, `\s` refers to whitespace.  Without the backslash it would be just the letter `s`. I mention this because Rubular's error message is a pretty clear hint as to what you need to do if you understand what it means.

Answer (score 7):

When you use the `//` regex literal, you need to escape `/` using a backslash as `\/`. When you want literal `/` in your regex, it is usually simpler to avoid using the `//` literal. For example, use `%r` literal with any delimiters that would not cause conflict.

```
%r{/}
```

By the way, Ruby onigmo regex engine does not allow look behind with variable length, so your regex will return an error anyway.

Comment: When I do what you said I also see this error: Forward slashes must be escaped.

Comment: @user3426797 As long as using Rubular, you cannot do what I suggest. Test that without using Rubular.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent wheels, especially ones that work:

```
require 'uri'

URI.split('http://user:passwd@www.example.com:81/path/to/index.html?foo=bar#baz')
# => ["http",
#     "user:passwd",
#     "www.example.com",
#     "81",
#     nil,
#     "/path/to/index.html",
#     nil,
#     "foo=bar",
#     "baz"]
```

Or:

```
require 'addressable/uri'

uri = Addressable::URI.parse('http://user:passwd@www.example.com:81/path/to/index.html?foo=bar#baz')
uri.authority # => "user:passwd@www.example.com:81"
uri.fragment # => "baz"
uri.host # => "www.example.com"
uri.password # => "passwd"
uri.path # => "/path/to/index.html"
uri.port # => 81
uri.query # => "foo=bar"
uri.query_values # => {"foo"=>"bar"}
uri.scheme # => "http"
uri.to_hash # => {:scheme=>"http", :user=>"user", :password=>"passwd", :host=>"www.example.com", :port=>81, :path=>"/path/to/index.html", :query=>"foo=bar", :fragment=>"baz"}
uri.user # => "user"
```

Between the two, [Addressable::URI](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/api/) is more full-featured and follows the specs very closely. Ruby's built-in [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) is good for lighter-weight lifting.

Root around in their code and you'll find the regular expressions used to tear apart a URL; You'll also see that they aren't trivial because URLs can be quite "interesting", where "interesting" means you'll scream and pull out your hair. See the [URI RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) for more information. See "Parsing a URI Reference with a Regular Expression" in that document for a suggested pattern.

---

> ...I do a exercise from codewars and I not allowed to use require

First, if so, why are you asking for help on how to write this? You are supposed to figure these things out yourself.

That said, try what has already been created. This uses the pattern in the RFC:

```
URI_REGEX = %r!^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?!
uri_captures = 'http://user:passwd@www.example.com:81/path/to/index.html?foo=bar#baz'.match(URI_REGEX).captures # !> assigned but unused variable - port
# => ["http:",
#     "http",
#     "//user:passwd@www.example.com:81",
#     "user:passwd@www.example.com:81",
#     "/path/to/index.html",
#     "?foo=bar",
#     "foo=bar",
#     "#baz",
#     "baz"]
user, passwd, host, port = uri_captures[3].split(/[:@]/)
host # => "www.example.com"
```

---

For further convenience, here's a simple pattern to provide named captures:

```
URI_REGEX = %r!^((?<scheme>[^:/?#]+):)?(//(?<authority>[^/?#]*))?(?<path>[^?#]*)(\?(?<query>[^#]*))?(?<fragment>#(.*))?!
uri_captures = 'http://user:passwd@www.example.com:81/path/to/index.html?foo=bar#baz'.match(URI_REGEX)
authority_captures = uri_captures['authority'].match(/(?<user>[^:]+)?:?(?<passwd>[^@]+)?@?(?<host>.+)(:(?<port>\d+)?)/)
authority_captures['host']
# => "www.example.com"
```

Comment: Your idea works the only problem is that I do a exercise from codewars and I not allowed to use require. So this is not working.

Comment: Then look at the pattern in the RFC. It's well-tested. See the additional info in the answer.